# Mask password in user input

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013, I want the user to enter his/her name and password. I am using msg inputbox command.

How do I mask the password as *** and use this password to login?

Comment: It is impossible with `InputBox`. You need to create your own user form with TextBox control. Here is article from Microsoft about that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa164894

Comment: Is it really that important to mask the inputbox's typed input? Anyone shoulder surfing can look at the keyboard just as easily as they can the computer screen.

Comment: yes I suppose, it is just a standard process where I will have to mask the password